# Apache2 install Error . apache2-bin

Tags: apache2

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Well, what about `sudo apt install apache2-bin`?

Comment: <blink>apache2-bin : Depends: libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 but it is not going to be installed or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-odbc but it is not going to be installed or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql but it is not going to be installed or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-freetds but it is not installable
               Depends: libaprutil1-ldap but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Have you tried removing the package, finishing any updates, and then re-installing it? Or is it a live system where removal is not an option?

Comment: Solved it  . . . .

Comment: Might be useful for some who cannot "solve it" with no hints https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114235/apache2-bin-cant-install-lubuntu-must-be-ugraded-to-2-4-29-1ubuntu4-5