# Apache2-bin can't install, lubuntu must be ugraded to 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.5?

Tags: apt, lubuntu, apache2

*Not a copy of [Apache2 install Error . apache2-bin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920082/apache2-install-error-apache2-bin) , not the same error and "ok, I solved it" comment by OP...*

I'm trying to install apache2 in order to install redmine on my Lubuntu 18.04.1 server.

When installing apache2, I have

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 apache2 : Dépend: apache2-bin (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9) mais 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.5 
devra être installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode 
« garder en l'état ».
```

English :

```
The following packages contain unsatisfactory dependencies :
 apache2 : depends : apache2-bin... but 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.5 must be installed
E: unable to correct, packages are in mode "keep state"
```

If I have to install `2.4.29-1ubuntu4.5` then OK but how ?

I have a LTS version of Lubuntu which was release-upgraded a few days ago :

```
> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

`dist-upgrade` does nothing at all...

- is there an "old" version of apache2-bin to solve this problem?
- how must be installed this `lubuntu4.5` thing?

Thank you!

---

@Organic Marble: here's the output, roughly copied from my phone's ssh app so I hope there's no typo

```
> sudo apt policy apache2
apache2:
    Installed : (none)
    Candidate : 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9
Version table:
      2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9 500
           500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
      2.4.18-2ubuntu3.8 500
           500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
      2.4.18-2ubuntu3 500
           500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt policy apache2` so we can see what version you are trying to install.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: You still have some Xenial (16.04) repositories; you should update them to the Bionic (18.04) ones.

Comment: @fkraiem do you have a command for this ? Or how is it done ?

Comment: Just edit your sources.list, or whatever you use to manage your repositories...

Comment: Thanks, that revealed the problem, your bionic install is somehow pointing at xenial repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sources.list is problematic, it refers to xenial repos although you have a bionic install. Here is a sample bionic sources.list. I don't enable the source code repos and your country may vary as well. I removed all the comments.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: Changed all the xenial to bionic and now apache2 installs OK. Thank you! Any idea why it wasn't changed although the release upgrade ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea. I've always just done clean installs instead of upgrades.  I am glad you got it working!